# Spoofing CLVIsit using GPX file

Tags: ios, gpx

I'm trying track a user's visits to different locations with CLVisit in CoreMotion but as far as I know a user has to be in a certain location for an (unspecified) amount of time before iOS recognises it as a 'visit'.

I am spoofing the location in the iOS simulator by using a GPX file but when specifying multiple locations, the simulator moves between them slowly at a constant rate. How can I make it stay in one location for about 10 minutes and then move to a different one?

I have tried specifying the same location twice with time in between but it seems to be ignored and the simulator's location simply moves gradually between locations:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode"> 

    <wpt lat="53.381050" lon="-1.480209">
         <name>Regent Court</name>

         <time>2015-09-15T14:30:37Z</time>
    </wpt>

    <wpt lat="53.381050" lon="-1.480209">
        <name>Regent Court 2</name>

        <time>2015-09-15T15:00:37Z</time>
    </wpt>

    <wpt lat="53.3814213" lon="-1.4845926">
        <name>Information Commons</name>

        <time>2015-09-15T15:10:37Z</time>
    </wpt>

    <wpt lat="53.3814213" lon="-1.4845926">
        <name>Information Commons 2</name>

        <time>2015-09-15T15:40:37Z</time>
    </wpt>


    <wpt lat="53.380596" lon="-1.487715">
        <name>Student Union</name>

        <time>2015-09-15T15:50:37Z</time>
    </wpt>

    <wpt lat="53.380596" lon="-1.487715">
        <name>Students Union 2</name>

        <time>2015-09-15T16:20:37Z</time>
    </wpt>

</gpx>
```